# Has the Chinese government indicated what is the "red line" in the Russian invasion of Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, international-relations, china

[This answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/71113/11278) suggests that should Russia use a nuclear strike in Ukraine, even China would condemn it:

> By using weapons of mass destruction Russia would be condemned not
> just by the West, but also the most countries which are friendly to
> Russia, like China, would condemn such action as well.

[CBS News](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/china-russia-civilian-deaths-ukraine-full-picture/) mentions the relunctance of the Chinese officials to condemn [what very likely represents war crimes in the Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_crimes_in_the_2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine):

> Beijing — China on Wednesday said images of civilian deaths in the
> Ukrainian town of Bucha are "deeply disturbing" but that no blame
> should be apportioned until all facts are known.

I am wondering if any Chinese officials ever mentioned a "red line" in the Russian invasion, that is what Russian forces actions could trigger a clear Chinese condemnation.

Comment: They surely have those, but they have no reason to make them known in public.

Comment: "red line" = condemnation? Not much of a line IMO.